# execute mysql RESULTSET from given string

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

is that possible to execute result set from given pattern in mysql

like

i am using following code :-

```
String query = "select logintime from auditlog";
    pst = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();


            while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("logintime"));
            }
```

which results me :

```
2013-02-18 17:02:44.0
    2013-02-18 17:03:37.0
    2013-02-18 17:04:14.0
    2013-02-18 17:06:54.0
    2013-02-18 17:07:24.0
    2013-02-18 17:10:39.0
    2013-02-18 17:11:19.0
    2013-02-19 14:23:23.0
    2013-02-19 14:25:58.0
    2013-02-19 14:25:58.0
    2013-02-19 14:26:41.0
    2013-02-25 14:15:46.0
    2013-02-25 14:32:30.0
    2013-02-25 14:38:30.0
    2013-03-15 10:57:46.0
```

i need value from `2013-02-18 17:11:19.0` which is

```
2013-02-19 14:23:23.0
    2013-02-19 14:25:58.0
    2013-02-19 14:25:58.0
    2013-02-19 14:26:41.0
    2013-02-25 14:15:46.0
    2013-02-25 14:32:30.0
    2013-02-25 14:38:30.0
    2013-03-15 10:57:46.0
```

not all the values

Comment: please rephrase your question so that we can understand it and help you

Comment: also please post your code and query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 choices :

1. Modify the query:
   `select logintime from auditlog where logintime > '2013-02-18 17:11:19'`
2. Filter from app layer:

> ```
> String query = "select logintime from auditlog";  
> pst = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(query);  
> ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
>
> SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");   
> java.util.Date fistDate = sdf.parse("2013-02-18 17:11:19");   
>
> while (rs.next()) {  
>    String logtime = rs.getString("logintime");  
>    java.util.Date parsedDate = sdf.parse(logtime);   
>
>    if(parsedDate.before(fistDate)){   
>      continue;   
>    }  
>    System.out.println(rs.getString("logintime"));  
> }
> ```

Comment: i've update the post ... instead of `<` i put `>` pls try now

Comment: i tried 1 choice that results me    2013-02-18 17:02:44.0
2013-02-18 17:03:37.0
2013-02-18 17:04:14.0
2013-02-18 17:06:54.0
2013-02-18 17:07:24.0
2013-02-18 17:10:39.0

Comment: but i need to eliminate the above lines and show the results after  2013-02-18 17:11:19.0

Comment: i'm glad it work, but it should work also with the query since it does the same thing outputs all the dates bigger then `2013-02-18 17:11:19`